# Django get form with data from the database

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a form that allows users to edit their profile data. As such I want to have the most recent data from the database be displayed when the user goes to edit the form. Heres what I have so far:

```
# models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

# forms.py
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['location', 'birthdate']

# views.py
class EditProfileFormView(View):
    form_class = EditProfileForm
    template_name = 'forums/edit-profile.html'

    def get(self, request, username):

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404('The User "' + username + '" could not be found.')

        if (not request.user.is_authenticated):
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        elif (user.id is not request.user.id):
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Setting the form to form_class(None) is what gives me an empty form, however dropping user.profile in the same spot gives me an error 'Profile' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try populating the form with an instance

```
form = self.form_class(instance=user.profile)
```

Note: this would probably be easier with a standard [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView)